# What is the correct pronunciation for 'deshalb'

Tags: pronunciation

I've heard a lot of people pronounce it like, 'dashalb' but when I looked online for the pronunciation you can hear, 'deshalb'. Is this a regional thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct pronunciation is *deshalb* [ˈdɛsˈhalp], but you may hear it in many slight variations of the first vowel and the final consonant, e.g. [ˈdɪsˈhalp].
To me, *dashalb* doesn’t sound correct, but it may very well be a regional thing.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try to adapt to the proper pronunciation. I've been using the wrong pronunciation the entire time. Thank you.